# Check if a object is in a collection with Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a class called Event that hasMany User objects in it.

```
static hasMany = [users:User]
```

How would I check if a given User is in that collection? Is there a function to do this?

I thought users.find(GivenUser) would work, but apparently not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is how equality is evaluated for the object within the collection. Without knowing if you have implemented your own equals or hashcode for the object in your collection it's hard to say. However, you could always do something like this:

```
users.find{it.id == givenUser.id}
```

As pointed out in the comments it's better to use GORM to query for this if you have a bi-directional relationship. In that case it would be much easier and efficient to:

```
User.findByOtherObject(otherObject)
```

Comment: If you have a bidirectional relationship, User.someParentDomain, then you can actually do it faster, without loading all the User objects, with SomeParentDomain.findByUser(user)

Comment: Oops, I actually got it the other way around, sorry:

It is User.findBySomeParentDomain(parent) that you want